# Send list of elements from View to Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have this model:

```
public class CarListViewModel
    {
        public List<Car> cars{ get; set; }
        public int selectedCar { get; set; }
        public List<Material> materials { get; set; }

        // (...)
    }
```

And this model:

```
public class Material
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string lot { get; set; }
        public int quantity { get; set; }
    }
```

Then, in my view, I have a table where I will insert multiple values representing materials. The table looks like this:

[image]

I want, for example, to fill the first two rows of the table and send the values to the controller.

I tried to do this, but the materials list is null in the controller.

```
@model CarListViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Registar material";
}

<div class="material-registration-wrapper">
    <h2 class="title">Registo materiais - Carro</h2>

    @using (Html.BeginForm("MaterialDummy", "Material", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "materialRegistrationForm" }))
    {
        <table class="material-registration-insertion">
            <tr>
                <th>Material</th>
                <th>Lote</th>
                <th>Quantidade</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                @{List<Material> mList = new List<Material>();}
                @{Material m1 = new Material();}
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => m1.name, null, new { type = "text" })</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => m1.lot, null, new { type = "text" })</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => m1.quantity, null, new { type = "text" })</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                @{Material m2 = new Material();}
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => m2.name, null, new { type = "text" })</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => m2.lot, null, new { type = "text" })</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => m2.quantity, null, new { type = "text" })</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                @{Material m3 = new Material();}
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => m3.name, null, new { type = "text" })</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => m3.lot, null, new { type = "text" })</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => m3.quantity, null, new { type = "text" })</td>
            </tr>
            @{ mList.Add(m1); }
            @{ mList.Add(m2); }
            @{ mList.Add(m3); }
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => mList, Model.materials)
        </table>
        <table class="submit-table">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="submit-table">
                        <input type="submit" value="Submeter" class="submit-button" />-->
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    }
</div>
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong, or a better way for me to do this?

Comment: There is a lot of info on ModelBinding of lists in MVC. Take a look at this for example:  https://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/

Comment: There is no point in keeping  a hidden element for a collection. As long as the input names are correct, model binder is able to map it to the parameter. So build your input elements with names in the format `Materials[0].name` , `Materials[1].name`. How are you creating the rows for the Materials collection in the UI ?

Comment: You mean in the view? I just have a HTML table with some rows and some columns. I posted the code in the question.

Comment: Your current code will render a single row! Why do you say you want to "send first two rows" ? Where is the second row coming from ?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I deleted some code to make the post shorter. I just edited the post.

Comment: How does your HttpPost action method signature looks like ?

Comment: Btw, both of your comments helped me a lot. I managed to make it work. Thank you very much.

Comment: Also, if you have 3 hard coded rows, no need to use the helper method, simply use the html markup for the input element with the correct `name` attribute values

Comment: Ok. Thanks once again. Post an answer if you want, so I can accept it.

Comment: You can post an answer to your own question, if you think it will help other people as well

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Daniel Stackenland and Shyju I managed to make it work.

The only thing I needed was to add the values directly to the materials list of the CarListViewModel class like so:

```
<table class="material-registration-insertion">
    <tr>
        <th>Material</th>
        <th>Lote</th>
        <th>Quantidade</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.materials[0].name, null, new { type = "text" })</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.materials[0].lot, null, new { type = "text" })</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.materials[0].quantity, null, new { type = "text" })</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.materials[1].name, null, new { type = "text" })</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.materials[1].lot, null, new { type = "text" })</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.materials[1].quantity, null, new { type = "text" })</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.materials[2].name, null, new { type = "text" })</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.materials[2].lot, null, new { type = "text" })</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.materials[2].quantity, null, new { type = "text" })</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

When pressing the submit button, the values will automatically be sent to the controller.

Comment: like i mentioned in the comments. you necessarily don't need to use the helper methods. You can write pure html code for the input element. All you need to make sure is the `name` attribute value is good  so that the model binder can map the posted form data